# Trying to get a hand of cards to display suit symbol

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nullpointerexception, switch-statement

I'm working on a method that is trying to display suit symbols of hands, so instead of 4C it would be 4(club), where (club) is the unicode of the club symbol.

For the switch statement, the HEART, CLUB, etc are declared as strings at the top of my program for the proper unicode.

My problem is that when I run the method the line containing "Card card = cards[i];" is producing a null pointer exception, and I have no idea why.  Please help :)

I have "private Card[] cards;" at the top. When I try to do = hand.getCards it produces an error because ArrayList cannot be converted to Card[]

Here is my method right now.

```
private String displaySuits() {
    for (int i = 0; i < hand.getCards().size(); i++) {
        Card card = cards[i];
        suits.append(" ");
        suits.append(card.getRank());

        switch (card.getSuit()) {
            case SPADE:
                suits.append(SPADE);
                break;
            case DIAMOND:
                suits.append(DIAMOND);
                break;
            case CLUB:
                suits.append(CLUB);
                break;
            case HEART:
                suits.append(HEART);
                break;
        }

    }
    return suits.toString();
}
```

Comment: Can you post the declaration/initialization of `cards`?

Comment: Do you mean my card class?

Comment: Since you are trying to access to an element of `cards` by an index `i`, `cards` should be an array. Post its declaration/initialization, which I guess should be something like `Card[] cards ...`

Comment: I have "private Card[] cards;" at the top.  When I try to do = hand.getCards it produces an error because ArrayList<Card> cannot be converted to Card[]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to define the ArrayList of Card **cards** inside the method displaySuits.

```
private String displaySuits() {

    ArrayList<Card> cards = hand.getCards();
    StringBuilder suits = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++) {
        Card card = cards[i];
        suits.append(" ");
        suits.append(card.getRank());

        switch (card.getSuit()) {
            case SPADE:
                suits.append((char)'\u2660');
                break;
            case DIAMOND:
                suits.append((char)'\u2666');
                break;
            case CLUB:
                suits.append((char)'\u2663');
                break;
            case HEART:
                suits.append((char)'\u2764');
                break;
        }

    }
    return suits.toString();
}
```

Comment: That produces an error because ArrayList<Card> cannot be converted to Card[]

Comment: I just changed it for you.  You will also need to define "suits" somewhere as well.  Is that a StringBuffer object?

Comment: I'm not sure what a StringBuffer is, so probably not.

Comment: Then what is suits? Most of the List classes use Add not Append.

Comment: I'm sorry, but when I used your selection, it still does not show the card symbols.  The null pointer exception is gone, but it lists my cards as "Here are your cards:  2 7 6 A 5 T" Rather than their suit right next to the number

Comment: I just edited it. Fixed 2 bugs and looked up all the unicode characters for you. Maybe you can accept my answer now :-)

Comment: Thank you, but it still does not display them.  I'm not sure if it matters, but the cards like "4D" are type String, so I had to remove the char, but still does not work.

Comment: I think you should create another question with the specific problem you have. Since the issue with the null pointer that this question was about has been fixed.

Comment: I figured it out.  I needed to add an S to HEART, DIAMOND, SPADE, etc. 

Thanks so much for your help! +rep

Answer (score 1):

As you are using an `ArrayList`, don't declare `cards` as an array `Cards[]`, but as

```
private List<Card> cards;
```

initialize it in the class constructor (good programming practice)

```
cards = hand.getCards();
```

and you have to access elements like

```
cards.get(i);
```

**Notes:**

- Don't forget that `ArrayList`s are different from arrays.
- Don't forget to declare and initialize `suits`, something like:

  `StringBuilder suits = new StringBuilder();`

Comment: I don't think you would want to make cards global to the class because its state is being controlled by the hand object.

Comment: I don't think it's clear enough because he has not gave further information about the classes he is using. I made that assumption since he mentioned he had declared `cards` as private. But what you are telling would be totally valid. If he just needs `cards` for displaying purposes, he should declare it as a local object.